PWA: notification sound, vibration , sound reminders without user gesture
I am currently developping an ordering-management-system. I chose PWA mainly for budget and skills reasons.
For this app, I need some important features to make sur the orders will be seen by the users:

Push notifications -> implemented: works as expected

Sound and vibration at order reception -> do not work as expected, user needs to interact with the app to trigger the sound ..

Sound and vibration reminder if order not acceped (in background) -> same problem as the feature 2


What should I hope from my PWA , is there some workaround to achieve what I want ? Is native apps the only way to achieve what I want ?
